# Android Hashmap issue

Tags: android, hashmap, android-sqlite

I have a piece of code which basically synchronises data between an online database. However I am getting an error on one particular line of code (`map.put("id", obj.get(mydb.WEB_ID).toString());`) where an integer value is obtained from the android sqlite databasse and submitted to the online database. The full cose is as displayed below :

```
public void updateSQLite(String response){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> syncL;
    syncL = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Create GSON object
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    try {
        // Extract JSON array from the response
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
        System.out.println(arr.length());
        // If no of array elements is not zero
        if(arr.length() != 0){
            // Loop through each array element, get JSON object which has userid and username
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                // Get JSON object
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                System.out.println(obj.get("web_id"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("phone_id"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("msg_id"));
                mydb.updateWebSync(obj.get(obj.get("phone_id").toString(), obj.get("msg_id").toString(), obj.get("web_id").toString());

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("id", obj.get(mydb.WEB_ID).toString());
                map.put("p_id", obj.get(mydb.COLUMN_ID).toString());
                map.put("s", "1");
                syncL.add(map);
            }
            updateMySQLSyncSts(gson.toJson(syncL), "syncsts");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Messages success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Messages error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my android sqlite database, the value of `mydb.WEB_ID` is stored as an integer. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: what kind of error ? Compile time or runtime ? What happens if instead of `obj.get(mydb.WEB_ID).toString()` you use `String.valueOf(obj.get("web_id"))` ?

Comment: The error is still the same. With regards to whether it is a compile time or runtime error, i don really know the difference but the error starts something like `13704-13704/? W/System.err:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake...I was calling the database column name in the `HashMap` which is different from the json variable. Thanks all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hashmap<String,String>
```

it only contains String values. So you have to convert it to String.
with using

```
toString()
```

function it ll give you error.

Try with

```
String.ValueOf(obj.get("web_id"))
```

it ll convert the interger value to String and your problem gets resolved.

Happy coding. `:P`

Comment: just print your (obj.get("web_id")) in your logcat and give me that value.

Comment: Try with this code First check the length() of the content what you getting from the DB and if the length() >0 then convert it. So just add if((obj.get("web_id")).toString().length()>0)